# Collision detection not working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to this and my game consist of a wide cube and a ball, the ball rolls on the cube platform like a ball in maze game. the ball drops trough the platform when i tilt to fast.(not that fast even). i tried multiple settings on the rigid body component and nothing worked. any pointers?

Comment: Does this refer to Unity3d? Then please add the relevant tag. Also, without more details your question cannot be answered.

Comment: yes it does, sorry first time

Comment: @STR44THOND You could try setting the collision detection to continous, or add more detail to your question so we know exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: i did that. i tried continuous speculative and dynamic. still not working

Comment: @GabRioBlu i have a ball in puzzle game where the platform tilts and the ball rolls as the platform tilts.

the problem i am having is that when the ball is on the edge of the platform and i tilt the platform, the ball drops though the platform(i have to tilt the platform at an super slow speed to make it work). i have used a few combinations of discrete, continuous speculative and dynamic. nothing worked.

the gravity is still -9.81 and all the material on the ball and platform is both materials with zero friction

Comment: @STR44THOND could you try sending us a gif of it so we can see what exactly happens?

Answer (score 0):

Might be wrong but from what I know when solving collisions Unity assumes everything has RigidBody or doesn't move, I assume only a ball in your project has rigidbody, but both ball and cube can have their position/rotation changed from script so what I suggest is to attach rigidbody to the cube and set it to `kinematic` so it won't move on its own and then move it via [RigidBody.MoveRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) method to make sure collision is detected.